# Deployment Issues with BasicNFT on Sepolia Network Using Foundry: Mismatched Bytecode and Successful Deployment

Tags: etherscan, nft, erc-721, foundry, sepolia

While deploying a smart contract using Foundry on the Sepolia test network, I'm encountering an issue. The deployment seems successful, but I'm facing a challenge verifying the contract's bytecode. Here is the summary of what I did and the problem I'm facing:

**Environment:** I'm working with Foundry for smart contract development. The repository for this project is at https://github.com/AryanGodara/foundry-nft.

Deployment Process: I used the following command to deploy my contract, BasicNft, to the Sepolia network:

```bash
deploy:
    @forge script script/DeployBasicNft.s.sol:DeployBasicNft $(NETWORK_ARGS)
```

**Issue:** The contract seems to deploy successfully to the network, as indicated by the successful transaction hashes and contract addresses provided in the terminal output. However, I encountered a problem during the verification stage. The terminal output states:

```bash
We haven't found any matching bytecode for the following contracts: [0x4568d1fb5701c79338b765e00428c875c45a4e34], [0xf05780540786f3351aa5aa8213b97f80924d902f].
```

This message appears for both deployment attempts I made, each with a different contract address.

**Questions:**

Why is the bytecode not matching, and what does this mean for my deployed contracts?
Do I follow specific steps to ensure the bytecode matches when deploying with Foundry?
Could this be an issue related to the compiler version or the way the contract is written?
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding the cause of this mismatch and how to prevent it in future deployments.

Thank you in advance for your help!